# Sum numbers and display them

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

i want to sum numbers in a databse for each person

like that:

```
        db.each("SELECT Person FROM Persons", function(err, row){
            var person = row.Person
            db.each("SELECT SUM(numbers) as sum1 FROM Persons WHERE Person = '"+person+"'", function(err, row){
               console.log("Sum"+ person+" "+ sum1);
           });
        });
```

but everytime there comes an error it says : " ReferenceError: sum1 is not defined"

Comment: Where is sum1 defined? maybe missing `row.sum1` ?

Comment: @taguenizy i througth it will be done by the database with "SELECT ...  as sum1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
console.log("Sum"+ person+" "+ sum1);
```

With

```
console.log("Sum"+ person+" "+ row.sum1);
```

as `sum1` is not defined

Comment: jep that is exactly what i mean thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `sum1` in your sql query, but not in JavaScript. The error is because of the `sum1` js variable in line:

```
console.log("Sum"+ person +" "+ sum1);
```

Should declare it also with `var sum1 = ...`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set value to variable 'sum1' before printing on console

```
var sum1=row.sum1;
```

I think this gona work try it.

Thank you.

Comment: jep just like that also works if you do it like this (console.log('Sum: '+row.sum1))